# MySQL: find IDs with constatnly increasing values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
create table my_table
(
 SubjectID int,
 Date Date,
 Test_Value int
);

insert into my_table(SubjectID, Date, Test_Value)
values
 (1, '2014-01-01', 55),
 (1, '2014-01-05', 170),
 (1, '2014-01-30', 160),
 (2, '2014-01-02', 175),
 (2, '2014-01-20', 166),
 (2, '2014-01-21', 160),
 (3, '2014-01-05', 70),
 (3, '2014-01-07', 75),
 (3, '2014-01-11', 180)
```

I want to find IDs with constantly increasing Test_Value over time. In this example, only SubjectID 3 satisfies that condition. Could you write the code to find this out? Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: Before you worry about "most efficient", worry about "gives the correct answer."

Comment: It might be better to do this outside of MySQL.  In whatever language you are using.

Comment: There are about 50 million rows and 11 million IDs in the data set that I am working on. It would be better if this could be done in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM my_table t1
    INNER JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.Date > t1.Date AND t2.Test_Value < t1.Test_Value AND t1.SubjectID = t2.SubjectID
    WHERE t1.SubjectID = o.SubjectID
)
```

The inner query would select all the entities that **DO VIOLATE** the requirements: they have later dates with least values. Then the outer select entities that do not match ones from the inner query.

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a7ba/12

PS: presumably if you only need an id - use `SELECT DISTINCT SubjectID`

Comment: I tested it, doesn't work =( Maybe move inner query to LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Peter: try again http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a7ba/12 (missed the condition for matching IDs)

Comment: Nice, you added `AND t1.SubjectID = t2.SubjectID` and it works now. I removed my answer, yours is much better

Comment: @Peter: yup, missed the obvious part :-S

Comment: one thing - wouldn't be [this](http://pastebin.com/UzNeGcwZ) faster? (I got rid of `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`)

Comment: @Peter: it needs an additional check on a real data. My personal opinion: most likely the execution plan will be very similar (for the latest and greatest mysql version)

Answer (score 0):

If the values are not monotonically increasing, then there is at least one case where adjacent values decrease.  Hence, you can reduce this problem to just looking at the previous value:

```
select t.SubjectId
from (select t.*,
             (select TestValue
              from table t2
              where t2.SubjectId = t.SubjectId and
                    t2.Date < t.Date
              order by t2.Date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_Test_value
      from table t
     ) t
group by t.SubjectId
having coalesce(sum(Test_Value < prev_Test_value), 0) = 0;
```

Comment: If there is only one entry for a particular `SubjectId` - this query won't return it (since `prev_Test_value` will be null)

Comment: @zerkms . . . I kept thinking . . . "The `NULL` is okay.  It'll skip it and move to the next value.  It doesn't affect the sum()."  But of course it does as you point out.